# Updating DataGrid View in Multithreaded Environment

Tags: c#, c++, multithreading

I have set of c++ dlls and a c# exe . My c++ dlls are multi-threaded and they put data into a Database. My c# exe uses Background worker . My c# exe gets these data to a Data table asynchronously. To achieve this I am using named Mutex. My problem is when I assign this Data Table to my grid view It is crashing. I am using delegates and Begin Invoke .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With begin invoke do you mean myDelegate.BeginInvoke?
you could try myForm.Invoke this runs the delegate on the UI Thread...

Comment: After Using Form.Invoke also it is crashing

Comment: well its hard to help you if you just say its crashing, you gotta be more specific.

Comment: After Invoke I release a mutex so that my c++ dlls can again use the database. My Grid is also getting updated but it crashes the moments it is updated.

Comment: What type of crash? What did C# write in stack trace?

Comment: It works perfectly in Debug mode. where as when I directly launch the exe it is crashing